# build-impl.xml:1022: The module has not been deployed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

As this is my first post in this forum and if i make any mistake please forgive me. Well i am using netbeans ide 7.2.1 version and Apache tomcat which is inbuilt in it. i have a Web Application project which was running nicely but all of a sudden i came to an error as mentioned below :

```
deploy?    config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FSourya%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext2934387861047212056.xml&path=/EmployeeInformationSystem
http://localhost:8084/manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FSourya%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext2934387861047212056.xml&path=/EmployeeInformationSystem
O:\NetBeansProject\EmployeeInformationSystem\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1022: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
```

There are some previous thread mentioning this problem but i could'nt find a proper solution among that. I have tried to build & clean it several times but still no solution.
The link in the above mentioned error i.e in xml line 1022 the codes are :

```
1021  <target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
1022  <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
1023  </target>
```

And also when i am trying to create a new web application it is showing the same error that it cannot build it. So what i am supposed to do now? Thanks in advance..

Comment: You are supposed to see the server log for details.

Comment: Ya i tried to see the server log from the netbeans service tab and then right clicking on my apache server and then 'show server log' but it's opening an empty tab in the bottom along  with the header Apache tomcat 7.0.27.0 log. but also i am getting this while the project is deployed `WARNING *********** NetBeans HTTP Monitor ************
HTTP requests cannot be recorded most likely because the NetBeans HTTP Server is not running. Go to the IDE and start the server from within the IDE to fix this problem.`

Answer (score 0):

The exception only means that the deployment did not work out - for whatever reason. If this is not the whole stack trace then search for a more significant exception. If you can not find anything revert either your project step by step and / or install a second instance of tomcat then try to run it there.

To start with application containers it's really helpful to use a code versioning tool like Subversion or Git to compare project stages (of course you can also use IDE built in features to not mess tools that are supposed for other things :-) ). Like this you can find out what changed. This will save you a lot of time - certainly when you let the IDE generate things for you...

Answer (score 0):

Late reply but just in case, check if the manager folder is present under tomcat's webapps folder. If not just copy this from the zip/tar file and it should deploy just fine.